# Casting to List<T> subtype in Linq-to-Entities query

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Consider three classes:

```
public class MyChildDto
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class MyChildDtos : List<MyChildDto>
{
    public MyChildDtos(List<MyChildDto> myChildDtos)
        : base(myChildDtos)
    {
    }
}

public class MyParentDto
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public MyChildDtos Children {get; set;}
}
```

I also have a collection of entities I would like to query and map to a parent object, like such:

```
public MyParentDto GetParentDto(int id)
{
    return DbContext.MyParentEntities.Select(p => new MyParentDto
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            Children = p.MyChildEntities.Select(c => new MyChildDto
            {
                Id = c.Id,
                Name = c.Name
            }).ToList()
        });
}
```

(Assume for the sake of argument that the MyChildDtos class is needed; I am just presenting a simplified example.)

The issue I am having is converting the result of the `MyChildEntities` Select to the appropriate type.  With the code above, I receive an error that the type cannot be implicitly converted (from `List<MyChildDto>` to `MyChildDtos`) but an explicit conversion exists.  However, when I attempt the explicit conversion, I receive an error that "LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types".  Similarly, if I attempt to construct the `MyChildDtos` list explicitly (i.e. passing the Select result into the ctor), I receive an error that Linq-to-Entities only supports using default constructors from within the query.

Is there some way I can cast the `List<MyChildDto>` result to the `MyChildDtos` (`List<MyChildDto>` subtype) from within the Linq-to-Entities query?

Comment: Have you tried overloading the implicit cast operator? (i.e. public static implicit operator MyChildDtos(List<MyChildDto> item) { return new MyChildDtos(item);})

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just shouldn't have the `MyChildDtos` type in the first place.  It is adding no value here.  The parent type should simply type `Children` as a `List`:

```
public class MyParentDto
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public List<MyChildDto> Children {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Because I've simplified the code for the sake of example; for the sake of argument assume the MyChildDtos is necessary.

Comment: @Andrew You should make it not be necessary.  Find a way to accomplish whatever it is that type is doing without subclassing `List`.  As you've already seen for yourself, you pretty well can't use the type at all as it sits.  Without knowing what your actual problem is there's no way for us to explain how you should actually go about solving it.